# Running web Application and Core logic on different server

Tags: java, networking

I have a web application which consist of a jar which is business logic of my web application now i want to ask that can it be possible that i run my web application on one server machine 
and my jar on other and my application connect to my jar with some network protocols.
So that if i had to change my business logic i had not to restart my application .
I call only a single function in jar which takes an argument as a object and it output an object to me ie i have only single point of contact to jar.

Comment: You'll still have to restart the "backend" if you change your business logic. What you're proposing isn't exactly uncommon, but detaching the backend doesn't seem to have much of a benefit if it isn't being used by multiple frontends. (Or a cluster of web servers running the frontend.)

Comment: i still want a dedicated m/c for my backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could expose your services through a technology like Spring Remoting (a far better choice than EJB/RMI), but there is one very important difference, which usually means major rework: the way you currently have it, all reference-typed arguments are passed by reference. Once you go remote, the **whole object graph** reachable from each argument will be serialized. This is a key moment that ruins the dream of transparently distributed objects.